# How to connect multiple apps to firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add multiple apps to one firestore database but couldn't find any working solution to it for me .

The one way is to add all apps to firebase project but its very difficult for me as the apps are already on other projects .

In realtime database you can do like this:-

```
val secondary = FirebaseDatabase
    .getInstance("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com").reference
```

from the docs:- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding

But its not there in firestore . If anyone know please help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to initialize a new [FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) instance and configure it to point to your other project, and do this once for each project.

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(...);
```

You then use this new FirebaseApp object to reach into their instances of Firestore using [FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#getInstance(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp)):

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(app);
```

This new FirebaseFirestore object will operate against the project configured in the FirebaseApp object.

Comment: How can I configure firestore rules for seperate apps / web apps?